# Add more data to session with next-auth

Tags: javascript, next-auth

I use next-auth with the credentials provider and a MySQL database. I would like to add more data from the database (like the user id) to the session than just the name and email.

This is the code I currently have. Obviously, I could just add the user id to the session in the session callback, but that would mean that I had to make more requests to the db which is not what I want.

```js
    export const options = {
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            name: 'credentials',
            credentials: {
                email: {
                    label: "email",
                    type: "email",
                    placeholder: "your email",
                },
                password: {
                    label: "password",
                    type: "password",
                    placeholder: "your password",
                },
            },
            async authorize(credentials) {
                let user = await GET(...) // database request
                // user includes user.email, user.password, user.id
                if (credentials.email === user.email && credentials.password === user.password) {
                    return user
                }
                else {
                    return null
                }
            }
        })
    ],
    callbacks: {
        async session({ session, token }) {
            session.user.id = 12 // would work with db request, but is not what I want
                return session
            }
        }
    }
```

What would be the best way to do that?